# z-index issue - drop down sf menu

Tags: css, z-index

I have an issue where the sub menu (dropdown) is behind the #main div. I have tried changing z-index values (ensuring div is positioned) but had no luck.

I have uploaded my progress to jsfiddle and wondered whether someone could see where I have gone wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/indigoclothing/8aGZC/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo is very complicated to work through and you have added the some CSS in the HTML as links and some as managed resources in jsFiddle which are loading twice, so it is **very** difficult to create a working fiddle. In future may I suggest that you just include the relevant parts that are not working. Constructing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) often results in figuring out where the problem is yourself as well :-)

That said, removing the following from the CSS section in the fiddle and the managed resources seems to fix it for me.

```
#header {
    z-index:2; // <-- remove this
}
```

The problem is that the menu and content have different stacking contexts - see [Overlapping and z-index](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) for an excellent description of this concept.

Comment: Great - thanks so much and the tips regarding a more simple example :)

Comment: Happy to help. I have added a link to my answer about overlapping which is very useful. Also there is a lot of `z-index` and positioning in your example. I tried disabling `z-index` and `position:xx` on `#menu, #header, .sf-menu` and the menu is still working for me in Chrome! You might want to look at simplifying that if you are in control of those styles.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using position: inherit; on the "main" div rather than relative, and modify the position of the element accordingly?

Comment: Just tried to do this on the jsfiddle page and doesn't seemed to have helped though I may be missing something else?